# JQuery FadeIn FadeOut Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I have a form which has a save button. When the save button is clicked it runs ajax to save the form contents. That works. What I am having troubles with is the save button fadein fadeout. The text of the save button is "Save as Draft". When clicked I would like it to fade out, change the text to "Draft saved at [time]" and then fade in to show that it was saved, and the time it was saved. After a few seconds I would like that button message to fade out and be replaced by the original "Save as Draft" button.

I'm thinking I have to nest the fades into functions, but my jquery fading talents are minimal and fading rapidly :)

Below is the success part of the ajax ....

```
success: function(data) {
    var date = new Date(),
    hours = date.getHours(),
    minutes = date.getMinutes();

    if (hours > 12) hours = hours - 12;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;

    var save_draft = '<div id="save-button" class="button-clone">Save as Draft</div>';
    var draft_saved = '<div id="save-button" class="button-clone">Draft Saved at ' + hours + ':' + minutes + '</div>';

    $('#save-button').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#save-button').replaceWith(draft_saved);
    $('#save-button').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#save-button').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#save-button').replaceWith(save_draft);
    $('#save-button').fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Comment: fadeIn/fadeOut, as other 'animations' are asynchronous, so, they will run almost simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers ...although the answers below work, the fadein's don't fade in, they just pop in with no fade. The fadeout's work great. Any idea how to get the fadein's to work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each animation is async, you need to call any other method inside the **callback function**.

**EDIT**

Sorry, it wasn't working. Adjusted with `fadeIn` too:

```
$('#save-button').fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $('#save-button').replaceWith(draft_saved);
    $('#save-button').hide().fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('#save-button').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $('#save-button').replaceWith(save_draft);
            $('#save-button').hide().fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Let me explain why this `hide()` is being needed:

When you `fadeOut` some element, jQuery puts `display: none` directly to that HTML. But you is replacing with another HTML (by `replaceWith()` method). But `fadeIn()` only fades elements that was hidden. So, we need to hide the new HTML and then the `fadeIn()` happens.

Comment: Thanks ...works, but the fadein's do not fade in ..they pop in.

Comment: @Mark, I updated with a complete working code sample and also explained why this updated was needed.

Comment: Perfect ...that makes sense ...thanks so much! I had tried to use empty and hide but was having trouble with when and where to place all of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You need to nest. Try something like this...

```
var date = new Date(),
hours = date.getHours(),
minutes = date.getMinutes();

if (hours > 12) hours = hours - 12;
if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;

var save_draft = '<div id="save-button" class="button-clone">Save as Draft</div>';
var draft_saved = '<div id="save-button" class="button-clone">Draft Saved at ' + hours + ':' + minutes + '</div>';

$('body').append(save_draft).;

$('#save-button').fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $('#save-button').replaceWith(draft_saved);
    $('#save-button').fadeIn(1000,function(){
        $('#save-button').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('#save-button').replaceWith(save_draft);
            $('#save-button').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks ...works, but the fadein's do not fade in ..they pop in.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$('#save-button').fadeOut(1000, function(){
$('#save-button').replaceWith(draft_saved, function(){
$('#save-button').fadeIn(1000, function(){
$('#save-button').fadeOut(1000, function(){
$('#save-button').fadeIn(1000);
}););}););}););});
```

I didn't indent the code so it doesn't look messy
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks ...works, but the fadein's do not fade in ..they pop in.